# Regarding electric field lines in three js

Tags: three.js

I would like to illustrate coulomb's law.I want to do 2 things.

1.I would like to show the force between any charge and resultant force.

2.And I want to show the electric field due to one charge on other.

I am done with the first one.So,how can I do the second one using three js?

[image: This is what I have done till now.]

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="DragControls.js"></script>
    <script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>

    <script src= "ThreeCSG.js"></script>
    <script src="ObjectControls.js"></script>
    <script src="stats.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dat.gui.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "object.js"></script>

    <script>
        objects=[]
        var gui;
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
                    var IsDragRunning=false;
                    var objectDragging;


        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

       // var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
        camera.position.z = 60;

        var dragElements = [];

        var dragControls = new THREE.DragControls( dragElements, camera, renderer.domElement );
        dragControls.addEventListener( 'dragstart', function ( event ) { /*controls.enabled = false;*/
                    IsDragRunning=true;} );
        dragControls.addEventListener( 'dragend', function ( event ) {
                        IsDragRunning=false;
                    /*controls.enabled = true;*/ } );

        scene.background = new THREE.Color("#FDF6D5");
        var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(  );
                    //text geometry

                    var myfont;

                    function text(object,text1){

                                if(!myfont){
                                        var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
                                                loader.load( 'optimer_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {
                                                    var count = 0;
                                                    myfont = font;
                                            });
                                        }
                                if(myfont){
                                var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( text1, {
                                        font: myfont,
                                        size: 1,
                                        height:0,
                                        curveSegments: 12,
                                        bevelThickness: 0.1,
                                        bevelSize: 0.1,
                                        bevelEnabled: false
                                });
                                var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(
                                        { color: "black",transparent:true,opacity:1.0,specular:"#B6C015"}
                                );
                                numberText = new THREE.Mesh( textGeometry, textMaterial );
                                numberText.position.set(2,1,1);
                                object.add(numberText);
                             }
                            }




        var ambientLight;
        var spotLight;
        ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(16777215, 0.5);
        ambientLight.position.set(-100,0,0);
        scene.add(ambientLight);
        spotLight = new THREE.PointLight(16777215);
        spotLight.position.set(60,10,40);
        spotLight.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(spotLight);
           ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(16777215, 0.5);
        ambientLight.position.set(-100,100,100);
        scene.add(ambientLight);
                    //dat gui
                    gui = new dat.GUI();

parameters =
{
    //x: 0, y: 30, z: 0,
    Charge:0,
    Er:1,
    //color: "#ff0000", // color (change "#" to "0x")
    //opacity: 1,
    visible: true,
    material: "Phong",
    charge: function() { charge_create(mag) ;
    findForce();}
};
var cubeX = gui.add( parameters, 'Charge' ).min(-10).max(10).step(1).listen();
//var epsilon = gui.add( parameters, 'Er' ).min(0).max(2).step(0.01).listen();
var mag=0;
var e=1;
cubeX.onChange(function(value)
{    mag = value;   });
//epsilon.onChange(function(value)
//{    e = value;
    //findForce(test.position);
//});

gui.add( parameters, 'charge' ).name("Add Charge");

gui.open();

        //columns law code
                    charge=[];
                    function charge_create(magnitude){
                        var t;
                        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.5, 32, 32 );
                        if(magnitude>=0){
                        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} );
                        t="+";
                    }
                        else{
                        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x000000} );
                        t="-";
                    }
                        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                        text(sphere,t);
                        scene.add( sphere );
                        sphere.position.set(Math.random()*40-20,0,0);
                        sphere.magnitude=magnitude;
                        charge.push(sphere);
                        dragElements.push(sphere);
                        return sphere;
                    }
                    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.5, 32, 32 );
                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x0000ff} );
                    var test = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    scene.add( test );
                    test.forceX=0;
                    test.forceY=0;
                    dragElements.push(test);
                    test.position.set(0,0,0);
                    text(test,"Test Charge");

                    /*charge_create(+1);
                    console.log(charge[0].magnitude);
                    charge_create(-1);
                    console.log(charge[1].magnitude);*/

                    //negative_charge=[];
                    var arr=new Array(20);
                    var resultant=null;
                    findForce(test.position);

                    function findForce(){
                        var fx=0;
                        var fy=0;


                    for(var i=0;i<charge.length;i++){
                        //console.log(position.x);

                        var r_square=Math.pow(Math.abs(test.position.x-charge[i].position.x),2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(test.position.y-charge[i].position.y),2);
                        var k=9*Math.pow(10,9)/e;
                        var force=k*charge[i].magnitude/(r_square);
                        force=force/1000000;
                        var y=test.position.y-charge[i].position.y;
                        var x=test.position.x-charge[i].position.x;
                        var angle =Math.atan(Math.abs(y/x));
                        if(y<0 && x>0)angle=-angle;
                        if(x<0 && y>0)angle=Math.PI-angle;
                        if(x<0 && y<0)angle=Math.PI+angle;
                        var force_x=force*(Math.cos(angle));
                        var force_y=force*(Math.sin(angle));
                        //arrowHelper

                        var dir = new THREE.Vector3( force_x, force_y, 0 );
                    //normalize the direction vector (convert to vector of length 1)
                        dir.normalize();

                        var origin = new THREE.Vector3( test.position.x, test.position.y, 0 );
                        var length = Math.abs(force);
                        if(charge[i].magnitude>=0)
                        var hex = 0xff0000;
                        else{
                            var hex=0x000000;
                        }
                        var arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir, origin, length, hex );
                        //text(arrowHelper.line,force);
                        //scene.add( arrowHelper );
                        //arr.push(arrowHelper);

                        if(arr[i]){
                            //console.log("asdas");
                            scene.remove(arr[i]);
                            arr[i]=arrowHelper;
                            scene.add( arrowHelper );
                        }
                        else{
                            //console.log("a");
                            arr[i]=arrowHelper;
                            scene.add( arrowHelper );
                            }


                        fx=fx+force_x;
                        fy=fy+force_y;
                        //console.log("force x"+fx+"   "+"force_y"+fy);

                    }
                    var net_force=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(force_x,2)+Math.pow(force_y,2))
                    var dir = new THREE.Vector3( fx, fy, 0 );
                //normalize the direction vector (convert to vector of length 1)
                    dir.normalize();

                    var origin = new THREE.Vector3( test.position.x, test.position.y, 0 );
                    var length = Math.abs(net_force);
                    var hex = 0x0000ff;
                    var arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir, origin, length, hex );
                    //text(arrowHelper.line,force);
                    if(resultant==null){
                        resultant=arrowHelper;
                        scene.add(resultant);

                    }
                    else{
                        //console.log()
                        scene.remove(resultant);
                        resultant=arrowHelper;
                        scene.add(resultant);
                    }

                    }
                    document.addEventListener("mousedown",onDocumentMouseDown);
                    var raycaster;
                    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
                        // event.preventDefault();

                        var mouse;
                        mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

                        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
                        raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                       raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
                       var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);

                       if (intersects.length > 0) {
                        if(IsDragRunning == true){

                            objectDragging = intersects[0].object;

                        }
                        }
                        console.log(IsDragRunning );
                        if(objectDragging)
                            console.log(objectDragging.name);
                    }

                    document.addEventListener("mousemove",onDocumentMouseMove);
                    var raycaster;
                    function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
                        // event.preventDefault();
                        if(IsDragRunning){
                            console.log("asd");
                            findForce(test.position);

                            //render();
                        }

                    }
                    //findForce();
                    var count=false;
                    var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
                            if(myfont && !count){
                                text(test,"Test Charge");
                                console.log("hello");
                                count=true;
                            }
                            //findForce(test.position);
            renderer.render(scene,camera);
        };




        render();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you clarify this phrase _"I want to show the electric field"_?

Comment: for every charge there will be some electric field associated field and when we bring another charge near to it that charge will be affected by this field. This is how I want to do check this link https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/charges-and-fields/latest/charges-and-fields_en.html

Comment: Something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/8laDGHV.png)?

Comment: yeah...like that

Answer (score 0):

This is not the ultimate solution, this is just the point where you can start from.

So, you can use a grid of `THREE.ArrowHelper()`

[image]

and then, when you add a charge in this field:

```
function setCharge(val) {
  var chargeGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 16, 12);
  var chargeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: val == 1 ? 0xff0000 : 0x0000ff
  });
  var charge = new THREE.Mesh(chargeGeom, chargeMat);
  charge.position.set(THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(cubeDim), THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(cubeDim), THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(cubeDim));
  charge.userData.charge = val;
  charges.push(charge);
  scene.add(charge);
  arrangeArrows();
 }
```

and its usage is like:

```
chargePositive.addEventListener("click", function() {
  setCharge(1)
});
chargeNegative.addEventListener("click", function() {
  setCharge(-1)
});
```

So, when you add a charge, you arrange your grid arrows, using the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) for each arrow, counting forces from all charges in the field:

```
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
var forceVector = new THREE.Vector3();
var directions = [];
var result = new THREE.Vector3();
function arrangeArrows() {
  arrows.forEach((arrow) => {
    directions = [];
    charges.forEach((charge, index) => {
      direction.subVectors(arrow.position, charge.position)
      normal.copy(direction).normalize();
      directions.push({
        dir: (charge.userData.charge == -1 ? normal.negate() : normal).clone(),
        force: 1 / Math.pow(forceVector.subVectors(arrow.position, charge.position).length(), 2)
      });
    });
    result.set(0, 0, 0);
    directions.forEach((dir) => {
      result.addScaledVector(dir.dir, dir.force);
    })
    arrow.setDirection(result.normalize());
  });
};
```

[image]

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/48cmjoLw/) example.

Also, you can use `THREE.LineSegments()` with `THREE.BufferGeometry()` and`THREE.ShaderMaterial()`, and do the same calculation on a GPU (with cooler visual effects):

[image]